# Clicking separate parts of an image link to different sections in the document

Tags: graphics, hyperref, links

Is is possible to make clicking on separate parts of an image link to different sections of the document.

for instance specify a region of a image (x, y, width height) and a hyperref.

(I am aware you can make clicking anywhere in an image link to a single section, but this is not what I need)

(I have seen [Link subsections of image to different labels (like html image map)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346878/link-subsections-of-image-to-different-labels-like-html-image-map) and [Possibility to ref link different areas of an image to different labels?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193696/possibility-to-ref-link-different-areas-of-an-image-to-different-labels) but couldn't see how to use what they had said)

Thanks

**EDIT**: What I have tried which handles a single link.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \hyperref[xxx]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image.png}}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak
\section{Section 1}

Some Text

\pagebreak
\section{Section 2}
\label{xxx}

Some Text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you post what you have tried so far.

Comment: So far I have only managed to make the whole image act like one big link, which I don't think is the right direction.

Comment: Without seeing what you have attempted, how can we say what is applicable or not? You already link to two different approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**REVISED APPROACH** (`\stackinset`)

Here, I just `\stackinset` any number of `\hyperref`ed `\makebox`es to encompass the desired portion of the base image.  The `\stackinset` can be specified relative to the `l`,`c`,`r` horizontal anchors and the `t`,`c`,`b` vertical anchors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref,stackengine}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \stackinset{l}{10pt}{t}{20pt}{\hyperref[topleft]{\makebox(100,100){}}}{%
    \stackinset{r}{30pt}{t}{40pt}{\hyperref[topright]{\makebox(50,40){}}}{%
    \stackinset{l}{40pt}{b}{50pt}{\hyperref[bottomleft]{\makebox(70,20){}}}{%
    \stackinset{r}{110pt}{b}{70pt}{\hyperref[bottomright]{\makebox(40,80){}}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}}}}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\pagebreak
\section{Section 1}
\label{topleft}

Some Text

\pagebreak
\section{Section 2}
\label{topright}

Some Text

\pagebreak
\section{Section 3}
\label{bottomleft}

Some Text

\pagebreak
\section{Section 4}
\label{bottomright}

Some Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL APPROACH** (`\clipbox`)

Here I use `\clipbox` to partition the figure into 4 [unequal-sized] quadrants, though there is, in theory, no reason you can't slice it into any number of rectangles.

I don't know how, but I am sure `hyperref` provides the means to make the `\hyperref` bounding box invisible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref,trimclip,stackengine}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
    \stackunder[0pt]{%
    \hyperref[topleft]{\clipbox{0pt .4\ht0{} .3\wd0{} 0pt}{\copy0}}%
    \hyperref[topright]{\clipbox{.7\wd0{} .4\ht0{} 0pt 0pt}{\copy0}}}{%
    \hyperref[bottomleft]{\clipbox{0pt 0pt .3\wd0{} .6\ht0}{\copy0}}%
    \hyperref[bottomright]{\clipbox{.7\wd0{} 0pt 0pt .6\ht0}{\copy0}}}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\pagebreak
\section{Section 1}
\label{topleft}

Some Text

\pagebreak
\section{Section 2}
\label{topright}

Some Text

\pagebreak
\section{Section 3}
\label{bottomleft}

Some Text

\pagebreak
\section{Section 4}
\label{bottomright}

Some Text

\end{document}
```

A click in separate corners of the image will take you to different pages in the document.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use, e.g., [`overpic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/overpic):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{overpic,picture}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{overpic}[%grid,% use this if you need help in finding coordinates
      width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \put(0,0){\hyperref[sec:first]{\makebox(50,75)[lb]{}}}%
      \put(50,0){\hyperref[sec:last]{\makebox(50,75)[lb]{}}}%
    \end{overpic}
    \caption{Example of link areas}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak
\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:first}
Some Text

\pagebreak
\section{Section 2}
\label{sec:last}

Some Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

The two red frames are the two link areas. If you do not want such frames, use, e.g., `hyperref`'s option `pdfborder`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{overpic,picture}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}% No borders around the hyperlink areas
    \begin{overpic}[%grid,% use this if you need help in finding coordinates
      width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \put(0,0){\hyperref[sec:first]{\makebox(50,75)[lb]{}}}%
      \put(50,0){\hyperref[sec:last]{\makebox(50,75)[lb]{}}}%
    \end{overpic}
    \caption{Example of link areas}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak
\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:first}
Some Text

\pagebreak
\section{Section 2}
\label{sec:last}

Some Text

\end{document}
```

The border will not be shown:

[image]

Nevertheless, the areas are still there.